# MySQL User defined variable within Doctrine and Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have the following Doctrine statement which works fine.

```
$query = $this->createQuery('r')
            ->select('u.id, CONCAT(u.first_name, " ", LEFT(u.last_name,1)) as full_name, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.gender, r.run_time')
            ->innerJoin('r.ChallengeUser u')
            ->orderBy('run_time')
            ->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY_SHALLOW);
```

I need to add a row count into this. Now I know with raw SQL you can do this;

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 as rank, u.id, u.first_name ....etc
```

So my question is, how can I get this to run with Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine?
I am using MySQL for this project.

---

Edit...
I figured it out..

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->standaloneQuery('SET @rank=0;')->execute();

$query = $this->createQuery('r')
            ->select('r.run_time, @rank:=@rank+1 rank, r.user_id, CONCAT(u.first_name, " ", LEFT(u.last_name,1)) as full_name, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.gender')
            ->leftJoin('r.ChallengeUser u')
            ->orderBy('run_time')
            ->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY_SHALLOW);
```

Add the standalone query in to set the variable, and swap the inner join to a left join.

Comment: Because it needs to be output as a json array for flash which manipulates it futher

Comment: Great! ok I will try to give you an answer :)

Comment: Sorry I tried, cant find a solution. I even try Doctrine_RawSql but it didnt allow to use variables in the select.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using MySQL, and no switches to other DBMS are foreseen, maybe you could try

```
$query = $this->createQuery('r')
            ->select('COUNT(u.id) as rank, u.id, CONCAT(u.first_name, " ", LEFT(u.last_name,1)) as full_name, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.gender, r.run_time')
            ->innerJoin('r.ChallengeUser u')
            ->orderBy('run_time')
            ->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```