# Doctrine: Select a record before update

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I found a solution to select the id of a row before it's updated using a single query in MySQL :

```
UPDATE data_table
   SET is_active = 0
WHERE token = 'some_token'
   AND is_active = 1
   AND @id := id;
SELECT @id;
```

But I would like to find a way to do the same using Doctrine. I tried :

```
$pdo = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$res = $pdo->execute("
    UPDATE data_table
       SET is_active = 0
    WHERE token = 'some_token'
       AND is_active = 1
       AND @id := id;
    SELECT @id;
")->fetchAll();
```

But I only get a `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error` and I don't find any workaround ...

Any ideas ?

---

Based on the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541999/mysql-user-defined-variable-within-doctrine-and-symfony) I found an answer :

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->standaloneQuery("
    UPDATE data_table
       SET is_active = 0
    WHERE token = 'some_token'
       AND is_active = 1
       AND @id := id;
");

$data = DataTable::getInstance()->createQuery('d')->where('id = @id')->fetchOne();
```

Comment: Check this solution : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541999/mysql-user-defined-variable-within-doctrine-and-symfony][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541999/mysql-user-defined-variable-within-doctrine-and-symfony

Comment: Thank you ! I found a solution using your link ! :)