# How to use user defined variables with MySQL?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a sql query adapted from [Rank function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3333665/390177) and I want to use it with Doctrine.
It seems that the system doesn't like my query and I don't know where to start to fix it.

This query works fine in MySQL itself, when I am using it with Doctrine I get a syntax error.

```
SELECT    l.*,
          @points:=l.playerPoints + l.organisationPoints,
          @curRank := if(@points <> @lastPoints, @curRank + 1, @curRank) AS rank,
          @lastPoints:= @points as points
FROM      leaderboard l, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r, (SELECT @lastPoints := 0) lp, (SELECT @points := 0) p
ORDER BY  l.playerPoints + l.organisationPoints DESC;
```

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 10: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable
>   | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration |
>   PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got '@'

I am using following PHP code:

```
$EntityManager->createQuery(...);
```

Is it possible to handle this with Doctrine 2?
It seems to be possible with Doctrine 1 ([MySQL User defined variable within Doctrine and Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6541999/390177)).

Answer (score 1):

**EntityManager::createQuery** is for DQL queries, I think [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/native-sql.html) is what you need (allow you to execute an arbitrary query and map result to doctrine entities).

Comment: I am with you, I haven't found yet another possibility.